# Wolfram Mathematica won't open Documentation Search

Tags: mathematica, wolfram-alpha

I was running a code I wrote and until some time everything was operational (using version 12.3). When I tried to revisit the same document after a while, it was not able to produce the same results as in the first place. What happens after the lines you could see in the screenshot below, is that a string of length 4 stops behaving as such out of a sudden. As I understand, there is a problem occurring which I cannot grasp, since I have not change anything compared to the first times I ran it. Is anybody familiar with anything similar?

[First steps of my code & bug pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKJfJ.png)